# How can we resolve a bet on a question of law?

Tags: lawyer, conflict-of-interest

Bob and Rob debate a question of law and do not agree. There isn't any material dispute between them to go to court about. They just want to find out what the legal truth is / who is right and who is wrong.

They can ask the question on this site and get a convincing answer but, should any of them later act in reliance on that answer and end up in a legal trouble, the answerer won't be liable. They both want an answer they can reasonably trust, and random people on the Internet just fall short of this requirement — no matter how seemingly reputable they are. Bob and Rob could even be debating just any good question from this site which one reputable member answers "Yes", another "No" — for example to kill time in [COVID-19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronavirus_disease_2019) lockdown.

They decide to bet. They are happy to pay to have their dispute resolved by an authoritative source (e.g. a lawyer, or a court of law).

How can they do that?

If any of them hires a lawyer, that lawyer will be protecting the interests of their client and therefore could potentially be biased to produce resolution that favours their client (lets them win the bet).

Can they *jointly* hire a lawyer? Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Once they've made the bet they have a contract and there is a material dispute, so one of them can sue the other. Although come to think of it they would each have to sue each other, and its possible that the judges in the two cases would come to opposite conclusions.

Comment: @PaulJohnson The contract would be that whoever is wrong does something (e.g. delivers a box of beer to the table). What's the material dispute? What to sue about? They both are ready to fulfil their contract obligations — just need to find out who is right and who is wrong.

Comment: Bob would argue that Rob is wrong, and therefore owes the money, but is refusing to pay.

Comment: @PaulJohnson A bet contract needs to specify how to find out who is right. Before that finding is executed, noone owes anything to anyone. That's what the court would say if Bob tried to sue Rob like you say.

Comment: You question seems to rely on the premise that it is possible to be *certain* as to the outcome of a legal question, and also that there exists a lawyer who would warrant the absolute truthiness of his legal conclusions. Does that distill out your central questions?

Comment: @user6726 Not quite. Bob and Rob do not seek absolute certainty but just that the lawyer will accept some responsibility for the answer (as opposed to us here who are free to give opposite answers as we're not responsible for them at all).

Comment: A closely related question would be "How to be 100%, legally reliably, sure whether I would be allowed to do something?".

Comment: If this is the US, are you already familiar with the cases and controversies clause of the constitution?

Comment: If the question is even remotely controversial or debatable you will find many legal experts on both sides of the issue.  I don't see how the word of one lawyer would settle the issue.  The other party would just find experts that agree with them.  If the question is not controversial then the problem wouldn't really exist in the first place.  Consider: "can the president postpone the election" ? the best answer is: probably not but if we get a Spanish flu style mutation of covid right before the election and many states don't have remote voting, who knows what the supreme Court would decide

Comment: Heck, just look at the recent example in Ohio where the lower courts said the governor could not postpone the election, he did it anyway and no one cared.

Comment: I have nothing against the accepted answer, but your criterion for deciding which answer to accept (i.e., the *incidental* matter of whether *jointly* hiring a lawyer is permissible) is inconsistent with the issue you purport to be your main concern in this post (i.e., what solution(s) are available for two laymen who have a question of law). You should make sure that there is no significant gap between how you formulate a question and what you ultimately intend to figure out. That way we all will know what to focus on.

Comment: @IñakiViggers I don't see any gap. Your solution only works where a "potential matter" exists between Bob&Rob and not for "unrelated debate merely intended to kill time". The accepted solution is universal.

Comment: @Greendrake "*The accepted solution is universal.*" That's where you are mistaken. It cannot be universal bc a lawyer's advice (1) is not binding; (2) might not even be applicable to actual situations (apropos of your mention of Bob or Rob "*act[ing] in reliance*" thereupon); and (3) inaccuracies in lawyer's advice usually are not actionable, let alone in unrelated contexts for which the advice was not intended. By contrast, your post & many of your comments highlight your concern about the binding nature and actionability of an inaccurate answer [to a question of law] on which someone relied.

Comment: @IñakiViggers The concern "about the binding nature and actionability" exists merely to weed out advisers that do not take approach diligent enough (as if they would in case of being accountable). It is just a litmus test for trustworthiness, not actual intention to hold to account.

Comment: @Greendrake "*It is just a litmus test for trustworthiness, not actual intention to hold to account.*" Again, that requires us to be mind readers. Just now you say it would be for purposes of *litmus test* only. But hitherto you had been mentioning acts in reliance, the risk of getting in legal trouble, your expectation for someone "*to share the blame at least, if not take it wholly*" if his answer is inaccurate, and so forth ... considerations that lead us to address your question in a certain way only to find out you actually had in mind something different than what you yourself described.

Comment: @IñakiViggers That's trade-off of written communication isn't it? I am no mind reader either. From my point of view the question was phrased clear enough to convey that "[t]hey both want an answer they can reasonably trust", not that they necessarily expect to actually use the answer and hold the adviser to account. I am sorry if I wasted your time. If you are still keen to keep educating me on how to ask questions you might want to email me how you would ask this one and I might have a look...

Comment: @Greendrake It's not about me "educating" you on how to ask questions. Others already told you the shortcoming(s) they sense in your question. My point is that you need to be consistent between what you ask (more so as you reinforce those impressions or concerns via comments), and the actual criterion for your choice of answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### You can jointly hire a lawyer

Yes, they can jointly hire a lawyer, coming at the lawyer essentially as one single entity: a partnership. The lawyer will research both sides of the question, and give the partnership a fair report.  The fee you pay may not deliver to one definitive answer, but it'll discuss all the likely angles.

However, if one of them needs a lawyer in an action against the other, that jointly hired lawyer will be "conflicted out". So Bob should

- identify the best lawyer in town in that particular area of practice, and retain that lawyer privately without telling Rob.
- Then, identify the second best lawyer in town, and recommend to Rob to use that lawyer for the "joint" lawyer.
- Now, when we come down to Bob vs Rob, Bob has the best lawyer, and Rob's is third best.

### Facts and circumstances will decide the matter

The biggest problem with floating a *hypothetical* question is that the *actual* facts and circumstances in your genuine flesh-and-blood case are likely to be different.  Understand that litigants are *especially stupid about this*.  There's a huge bias to believe matter X is relevant/on-point to their own case, when a neutral judge may not see it that way at all.

Likewise, there's a huge bias toward presenting your hypothetical in flattering terms, on the hopes of getting a more favorable ruling.  Then, when the real case comes up, the facts and circumstances differ too much, and the judge says "these facts don't fit your declaratory judgment". And now it's a new ballgame.

Your best bet, in areas of doubt, is to obtain legal advice and pay heed to it.

Comment: "Partnership" is the key word I should have thought about. Cheers.

Answer (score 10):

> How to resolve a bet on a question of law? should any of them later act in reliance on that answer and end up in a legal trouble, the answerer won't be liable.

If said act[ion] in reliance on the answer is about a potential matter to which Bob and Rob would be the parties, Bob or Rob could consider filing suit for *declaratory relief*. The decision(s) in that case would determine *ex-ante* the parties' rights or award if the issue materializes in the future.

Hiring some lawyer to decide the question of law is futile because the lawyer's conclusions are neither binding nor something that could be reviewed on appeal. Furthermore, there is the very realistic possibility that the lawyer himself might be clueless on that question of law. Oftentimes judges can --and happen to-- be clueless as well, but (1) the *binding* component leads to what is known as *the law of the case* of Bob vs. Rob, and (2) the decision may be appealed.

Bob and Rob could resort to arbitration to have the dispute decided. This would be the midpoint between just hiring some lawyer and pursuing a *declaratory judgment* in that the decision in arbitration would be binding.

The problem with arbitration is that judicial review would be unavailable even for questions of law, and even if the parties explicitly agree to preserve the right to appeal questions of law. This means that the arbitrator's decision could depart from the *legal truth* and yet be irreversible.

For instance, [*HL 1, LLC v. Riverwalk LLC*, 15 A.3d 725, 732 (2011)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/inmeco20110310250) points out that both Federal Arbitration Act and Maine Uniform Arbitration Act list *exclusive* grounds for vacating arbitration, and the appeal of any question of law is not among those grounds ("*[t]he Court held that the FAA provided exclusive grounds for vacating arbitration awards and that those grounds may not by supplemented by contract*").

Comment: Do courts of law actually make _ex-ante_ decisions anywhere? DaleM points that they do not resolve hypotheticals: "_almost the first decision of the US Supreme Court was that it wouldn’t tell Congress if the law they were contemplating was constitutional_". Also, does this answer essentially not stand if the matter between Bob and Rob is not even potential at all but simply a good question picked up from this site that they debate to kill time in covid lockdown?

Comment: @Greendrake "*Do courts of law actually make ex-ante decisions anywhere?*" That is exactly the purpose of [declaratory judgments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaratory_judgment): *legally binding preventive adjudication*. The 2nd follow up question is a non-sequitur: The arising of liabilities contradicts the premise that "*the matter between Bob and Rob is not even potential at all*. Regardless, applying in a real situation the conclusion someone came up with during an unrelated debate merely intended to kill time constitutes *unreasonable reliance*, and as such it cannot be remedied.

Comment: Whereas the matter between them is not potential, either of them would use the knowledge obtained from the authoritative source in any future matters with any other parties where  material circumstances are the same. Barring any changes in law that time may bring, I can't see why they can't expect the source to take responsibility for its advice. Simply put, if a lawyer or court A tell me that doing X is legal, I later do exactly X and get punished, I would expect A to share the blame at least, if not take it wholly.

Comment: @Greendrake "*I can't see why they can't expect the source to take responsibility for its advice.*" In the case of a judge, because of the disastrous doctrine of *judicial immunity*; of an arbitrator, because the scope of arbitrator's conclusions is limited to the specific debate between Bob & Rob only; and of anyone else, because his or her conclusions of law are not binding at all (otherwise every law school graduate could sue his professors whenever he loses a case), and the relation between Bob/Rob and the adviser would typically fall short of establishing a *fiduciary duty*.

Comment: Judges create case law which is binding on inferior courts; in this sense judges are responsible as far as Bob&Rob are concerned as they can always defend their actions by the case law. Professors can't be sued for what they teach indeed, but lawyers do have liability for their advice don't they?

Comment: @Greendrake "*in this sense judges are responsible as far as Bob&Rob are concerned*". That doesn't mean that the judge will take responsibility for his/her advice, rulings, or conclusions. If anything, the precedent created by that judge would be stricken whereas the reliant party would remain liable nonetheless. The whole mess would have no legal effect on the judge whatsoever. "*lawyers do have liability for their advice don't they?*" This can depend on so many legal and factual circumstances that it is impossible to give a general, definite answer.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for _ex-ante_ and declaratory relief only.

Answer (score 3):

"Agreement" is probably the first step: over what constitutes an authoritative source. As you allude, courts are authoritative, though access is limited to appropriately injured parties. Otherwise the court's opinion would be "advisory," which is typically proscribed.

You might consider paralleling the structure often used for factual resolution of insurance contracts. For example, if one is trying to determine the extent of hail damage from a storm, each party may be entitled to an appraiser's opinion. If the appraisers disagree, then they—not the parties—choose a third appraiser to "adjudicate" the disagreement. That expert's opinion is binding.

In your situation, if you could agree to abide by the decision of a suitably authoritative expert, you could skip the first layer of disagreeing, adversarial experts.

Comment: It's hard to imagine that an "authoritative expert" could be anyone but a lawyer. Hired lawyers have limited room for manoeuvre because of rules of client care/conduct. Are you essentially talking about hiring a lawyer _jointly_? Is this even possible? Will a lawyer be allowed to resolve a bet like this by telling both Bob and Rob what the "legal truth" is?

Comment: Maybe the details are otherwise, but it's hard to see how a bet situation would generate the standing required for declaratory judgment (if that's a thing in your jurisdiction). If it does, then maybe that's an answer. But this answer suggests resolving via private law: you agree to bind yourself to the decision, and the contract creates its own enforceability. Whether a lawyer could jointly represent you depends on the jurisdiction.

Comment: @Greendrake "It's hard to imagine that an "authoritative expert" could be anyone but a lawyer" - What about a professor of law, perceived to be expert in the particular topic?

Comment: @Lag As I understand it, such a professor would be breaking the law by giving legal advice without registration as a lawyer.

Comment: @Greendrake Oh, I didn't understand the scenario as a requirement for  legal advice.

Comment: @Lag That's not a requirement. But the law will recognise it as legal advice regardless. This is the crux of the question — access to legal advice is so constrained and regulated that bets like this are probably unresolvable.

Answer (score 0):

### The [philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com) stack is available

That’s the forum for finding the truth. Here we deal with the law.

If there is no dispute there is no legal question to be resolved. Bob and Rob can each follow the law as they believe it to be. If and when this leads to a legal dispute (between them or with a third party) the courts are available to resolve that dispute. That may or may not resolve the issue of law - if the particular dispute can be resolved without that, so much the better because the judiciary prefers to leave lawmaking to the legislature when they can.

Law is a practical discipline - the search for certainty belongs to philosophy or the sciences. Lawyers, engineers and doctors don’t care about the truth - they just want what works.

Comment: I specifically wrote "legal truth" and not just "truth" in the hope to preclude this kind of answer. "Is there contract or not?" That's a question of law. One answer will be truth, the other will be false. Without any philosophy.

Comment: @Greendrake I disagree - on the facts of one case there is a contract, on the facts of an almost identical set of facts in a different time and place, there isn’t. That’s the truth of law.

Comment: Okay. What if they bet on something like "is murdering people illegal?". Bob says yes, Rob says no. Kind of exaggerated example but you get the idea.

Comment: @Greendrake why do you think a court is interested in resolving a bet? Your example is poor because murder is illegal by definition- if the killing isn’t unlawful it isn’t murder. I understand what you are trying to say but courts do not resolve hypotheticals (at least in common law jurisdictions) - indeed, almost the first decision of the US Supreme Court was that it wouldn’t tell Congress if the law they were contemplating was constitutional. Now, if Bob and Rob can turn this into a real dispute - game on but it will be played by the rules of the court.

Comment: If courts were interested in resolving bets (and I knew that) I wouldn't be asking this question. But you now sound like the actual answer is "no way" which I would accept if it was saying that directly. The question Bob and Rob debate could in fact be any good question from this site, like whether something is legal. As it often happens, someone will answer yes, someone no. So Bob and Rob just need someone they both trust to say yes or no. But they perhaps won't trust anyone unless that person takes responsibility for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question contradicts itself:

> They just want to find out what the legal truth is / who is right and who is wrong.

Here you have said that the primary interest of each party is to know the truth.

> If any of them hires a lawyer, that lawyer will be protecting the interests of their client and therefore could potentially be biased to produce resolution that favours their client (lets them win the bet).

Here you have said that the primary interest of at least one of the parties is to win the bet.

It is not possible for both of these things to be true. If the first thing you said is true, there is no problem. Either party can hire the lawyer. The lawyer would be betraying his client's interests if he slanted his advice so his party would win the bet since that is not the client's primary interest.

Comment: I don't see any contradiction between the desire to be right (which would be proven by winning the bet) and readiness to accept being wrong. Taking chance to fulfil that desire is inevitably dependent on finding out the truth, which is why they want it. Whoever tells the truth needs to be impartial, so noone can hire their own lawyer.

Comment: Your response is also contradictory. Does each party want an unbiased answer or do they want to win the bet? It can't be both. If each party wants an impartial answer, then a party bound to do what either party wants would be impartial.

Comment: "_It can't be both._" — well, I say it can. Perhaps it boils down to the readiness to eventually accept that 2*2=4 when for whatever reason you are sure it equals 5. Having your own point (and willing it to be true so that your ego is happy) does not necessarily eliminate being happy to realise that you were wrong (and getting your ego stuffed).

Comment: @Greendrake Is this statement, from your hypothetical, true: "They just want to find out what the legal truth is / who is right and who is wrong."? You said it. You set up the hypothetical with this statement. Is it true?

Comment: It is true. You just need to bear mind _why_ they want it — because each of them already has an opinion of what the truth is, and they don't match, and both are so sure they are right so that they want to bet.

Comment: @Greendrake Then neither of them has any interest in getting a biased answer. A lawyer who provided a biased answer would be doing a disservice to both of them. Either of them could hire the lawyer.

Comment: That depends on the lawyer who could misunderstand their client that they just want to win the bet no matter what the truth is.

Answer (score -2):

### It is false to think that one has to be right and the other has to be wrong.

Law is in the eye of the beholder.  What's written by the legislature is not a done deal.  It has to be interpreted by judges, many times in actual cases to really know what it means (how it will be applied) and whether Bob or Rob is right.  And that's assuming they're not both wrong, lest you forget that possibility.

This subjectivity is all the more so the case if the disagreement between the two is based on some very technical nuance, perhaps a contested political one.

If they both hire the same lawyer, the lawyer can give his *best opinion* in good faith.  But that doesn't mean the lawyer is *right*.

### There is no *right* in law.

Written law is not completely deterministic.  Your results will legally depend on discretion of a police officer, district attorney, judge, and potentially jury.

Comment: Sorry but this sounds like pure demagogy. I agree that law is not deterministic. Still, right and wrong answers do exist. "_Is it a crime to randomly and intentionally kill people?_". This is a question of law, no matter how stupid it sounds. The right answer is  "_Yes, it is. The crime is called murder_". The wrong answer is "_No, you can do it any time_".

Comment: ......Unless you find yourself surrounded by people who have all demonstrated a direct and willful intent to end your life, like an angrier than normal angry mob.  Then you can kill them all intentionally and as randomly as you like....  In most states of the USA.....  But an example that clear is not one that Rob and Bob would be arguing about now is it.

Comment: I guess you could conduct a survey of the supreme court justices on the matter?  In writing.  At a time that there is an odd number of them currently appointed.  But you're not likely to find more than a couple who would be bothered over something so trivial.  And even then, they have a habit of dying, and things change when their replacements have a different opinion.  And by the way there's been times where the 9 of them can not form a single majority opinion (They can split 3 or more ways)

Comment: @BillyC. as to your comment: Killing members of an angrier-than-normal-angry-mob isn't that random, is it? The selection pattern is still well defined. - So you are left with "intentionally".